# What procedure should I do when I water my sunchokes?

Tags: watering, sunchoke

My sunchokes seem to getting bigger by the day, and may develop some rot if I'm not careful, so I was wondering how I should go about watering my sunchokes with "free" water to get the highest yield that I can possibly get.

Comment: The highest yield does not come from overwatering them so they rot. Unless you are in a particularly arid climate or a full-blown drought, they don't need to be watered at all.

Comment: @Ecnerwal so flood once a week now that they've been established?

Comment: Hi black thumb! I'm confused as to what "free" water means.  Would you kindly explain that? Also, it looks like Ecnerwal said they don't really need to be watered at all unless you're in an arid climate or drought. You responded back asking if flooding once a week would be the right method. Does that mean you are indeed in one of those climates? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's helpful to add climate to questions in general. Especially since you're seeking advice about very specific types of plants and yard design, that matters. Your profile says Zone 4a, but that doesn't tell us what your true temperature range is, how much it rains, number of hours of sun those plants get, what country you're in, and other things like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I'm growing them in a community garden (10X15), and have free water there I'm based in MN. Flooding a garden is you pile up the sides, and water until the ground is drenched, and turn the water off.

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Sounds wasteful of water, even if there is no direct cost to you. Hand watering allows you to inspect the plants for diseases, and insect damage

Answer (score 3):

Sunchokes are drought tolerant plants that prefer well drained soil. It would not be good to over water them in a poor draining soil.

There's no fixed periodicity to water them as it depends on your soil and weather. Unless you have indicator plants such as oleus plants (Coleus blumei) that droop when the soil is dry, you are either going to need to inspect the soil, or use a meter.  Normally, you'd want to water deeply when they need it.

Comment: What moisture amount do they prefer (percentage)?